# Job dependencies across several clusters

Tags: slurm

Let's say I submit a job to several cluster queues with `--clusters=a,b,c` and `sbatch` says that it was submitted with the id `ID` on cluster `a`.

Can I submit another job with the first one as dependency, but on a different cluster? Something like `--dependency=afterok:ID` and `--clusters=b,c`. To me this does not seem possible as `ID` is only relevant within the queue of cluster `a`, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the clusters are organised as a *federation*, job IDs are globally unique so this will work. If they are not part of a federation, job IDs are relevant only in the scope of each cluster, and your intuition is correct. See [this doc](https://slurm.schedmd.com/federation.html) for further information.

Comment: Thanks! I checked and the clusters I use are not federated. Since I still need to create a job with the first one ('ID') as dependency, I settled for `--dependency=afterok:ID` with `--clusters=a`.